# Running AppleScript without activating the window

Tags: macos, applescript, messages

I have a python script to read from Messages database and forward some specific new messages to specific contacts. It works but the AppleScript below to send message is making Messages.app appear.

I want it to send the message in the background without activating or un-hiding the window. Is this possible?

```
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
    tell application "Messages"
        set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
        set targetBuddy to buddy targetBuddyPhone of targetService
        send targetMessage to targetBuddy
        set visible to false --> this throws an error on terminal
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Do you to hide it from the user, or you just want to go back to the previous window after the script? You could just use `tell application "X" to activate` or maybe store the `frontmost window` before the script and summon it afterwards.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro I always keep my messages.app app in dock minimized and open, I want it to stay there. But now it steals the focus

Answer (score 2):

For Me adding:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Messages" to set visible to false
```

AFTER end tell, worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

You could include this code at the end of the script:

```
tell application "Messages"
  set miniaturized of window 1 to true
end tell
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564160/code-for-minimizing-application-window-in-mac

Comment: The OP stated, "I want it to send the message in the background without activating or un-hiding the window." and while adding what you've suggested nonetheless it doesn't really answer what was asked, in reference to the first quoted sentence in this comment, "Is this possible?" as the window if already miniaturized, it is un-miniaturized when the message is sent. Your suggestion just adds another visual disturbance to the flow and not in line with "I want it to send the message in the background without activating or un-hiding the window."!

Comment: @user3439894 funny story: I can't see your better ideia